# sql oracle: Listing records when there are more than N number of records stored within the same month

Tags: sql, oracle

EDIT: I Realized that the question I posted with this previously was looking for somthing different, instead of having at least N records within the same month, I needed N records within the same month with the same value saved in.

I am suppose to fetch from my records, if there is more than three records with the same Tradename stored within the same month.

An example of the record I have

```
TradeID      Tradename           PrescDT
------------------------------------------
1109         Panadol             sysdate-1
1123         Opioids             sysdate-3
1125         Doxycycline         sysdate-3
1138         Panadol             sysdate-14
1139         Panadol             sysdate-3
1141         Panadol             sysdate-5
1142         Codeine             sysdate-5
1162         Opioids             sysdate-14
1167         Codeine             sysdate-14
1168         Prednisone          sysdate-14
1170         Codeine             sysdate-21
1172         Codeine             sysdate-22
```

so it should return me with only this, where I only want the tradename and date

```
Tradename           PrescDT
------------------------------
Panadol             sysdate-1
Panadol             sysdate-14
Panadol             sysdate-3
Panadol             sysdate-5
```

I have tried using this but the returns me with nothing

```
SELECT pres.Tradename, pres.PrescDT
FROM PRESCRIPTION pres
    GROUP BY pres.Tradename, pres.PrescDT
    HAVING COUNT( TRUNC(pres.PrescDT, 'MM')) > 3;
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  Informix?

Comment: Also, you don't need the `WHERE` clause, as it is always true.  Take that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `count` to count number of row in each month and filter based on that count to get the desired result:

```
select tradename, prescDT
from (
    select p.*,
        count(*) over (partition by trunc(prescDT, 'MM')) as cnt
    from prescription p
    ) p
where cnt >= 3;
```

Comment: @Monomoni - it's because they satisfy your criteria. See this example - http://rextester.com/HWO14107